# Is there an easy way to convert the routes from the old string syntax to the newer callable syntax?

Tags: laravel

There are many routes in the project's `web.php`. Is there an easy way to convert them all to the new callable syntax (A recently upgraded Laravel 10 project from Laravel 7):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#routing

Update: As suggested, I tried to use Rector for Laravel, but I get an error.
This is the `rector.php` content:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Rector\CodeQuality\Rector\Class_\InlineConstructorDefaultToPropertyRector;
use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use RectorLaravel\Rector\StaticCall\RouteActionCallableRector;
use Rector\Set\ValueObject\LevelSetList;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        __DIR__ . '/routes'
    ]);

    $rectorConfig->ruleWithConfiguration(RouteActionCallableRector::class, [
        RouteActionCallableRector::NAMESPACE => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    ]);
};
```

But when I run `vendor/bin/rector process src` I get the following error:

```
 [ERROR] Cannot autowire service "RectorLaravel\Rector\StaticCall\RouteActionCallableRector": argument                  
         "$routerRegisterNodeAnalyzer" of method "__construct()" references class
         "RectorLaravel\NodeFactory\RouterRegisterNodeAnalyzer" but no such service exists.
```

Update #2: It worked after adding a random Set at the bottom:

```
return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        __DIR__ . '/routes'
    ]);

    $rectorConfig->ruleWithConfiguration(RouteActionCallableRector::class, [
        RouteActionCallableRector::NAMESPACE => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    ]);

    // added this
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        LaravelSetList::LARAVEL_CODE_QUALITY
    ]);
};
```

And it worked! Though it adds the full path `'App\Http\Controllers\SomeController'` instead of just the controller name and using it at the top with the `use` keyword, but that's an easier fix.

Comment: well you don't have to change them ... but no there is no automated way built in, you could write a script that could do it though

Comment: Thanks, yes it does work as is now but I like the new syntax. I will then work on a script that reads `web.php` and convert it accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector) for that, and more specifically the [upgrade rules for Laravel](https://github.com/driftingly/rector-laravel). That package contains a specific rule for this case, named [RouteActionCallableRector](https://github.com/driftingly/rector-laravel/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#routeactioncallablerector):

```php
// converts 
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');

// to
Route::get('/users', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Nice, going to give it a try. Btw can I install that on a separate empty project, copy the relevant `web.php` and use it? I do not want to try this action directly on my project so I want to try on a copy of the `web.php`

Comment: Edit: I meant a simple empty composer project, not a Laravel project. But I think I will just copy the entire Laravel project and do it there

Comment: Try it out and see what happens. But usually, you should not fear creating a seperate branch, install Rector on it, run the conversion (there's even a `--dry-run`  option), and inspect the changes before merging

Comment: thanks, I get an error (updated the post)

Comment: Sounds like you should check how autowiring happens in your code

Comment: Thanks. I just added a random set and it worked! But why? In my example I added `$rectorConfig->sets([LaravelSetList::LARAVEL_CODE_QUALITY]);` (Also updated the post). But why? What does this setList mean? I could just put any setList there like `LARAVEL_100`, `LARAVEL_80` and so on, but what do they mean?

Comment: Have a look at Rectors documentation at https://getrector.com/documentation/set-lists - `Laravel_100` means: apply all rules up to Laravel 10, `Laravel_80` means: apply all rules up to Laravel 8 (not those for 9 or 10)

Comment: Thanks. After reading the rector docs the `LARAVEL_X` part does make more sense. But I didn't find it on the laravel-rector docs. Do they just assume that we understand it from the rector docs?

Comment: If you think that their documentation should be improved, open an issue in their bug tracker - or provide a pull request to improve the documentation